# Not able to view or download file on iPhone + SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, iphone, odata, sapui5

This code works great on tablets and desktop, but when I try on iPhone it is not downloading any file. Please help

```
if (aData.ExternalUrl === "") {
  this.oModel.read("/GetAttachmentBase64Set('" + aData.DocumentId + "')", {
    success: function (oData, oResponse) {
      oList.setBusy(false);
      var dataURI = oData.EvAttachmentData;

      if (Device.system.tablet ||Device.system.phone) {
        window.open(dataURI, "_blank");
        return;
      }
      dataURI = dataURI.substring(dataURI.indexOf(",") + 1);

      var raw = window.atob(dataURI);
      var rawLength = raw.length;
      var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

      for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
        array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      var saveByteArray = (function () {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";
        return function (data, name) {
          var blob = new Blob(data, {
              type: "octet/stream"
            }),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          a.href = url;
          a.download = name;
          a.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        };
      }());

      saveByteArray([array], aData.Filename);

      oList.removeSelections();
    },
```

This code works great on tablets and desktop, but when I try on iPhone it is not downloading any file. Please help

Comment: See if it works with a smaller file size first. According to the documentation section ["Loading Large Amounts of Data"](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/966d67c8cc5046419d1b35556cd9e447.html#loio966d67c8cc5046419d1b35556cd9e447/section_LLAOD): >"Whenever you use methods like \[`ODataModel#read`\], your application must not load large amounts of data." \[...\] "[UI5] does not set limits on the amount of data to be loaded by your application. However, some browsers may do, which would cause your application to fail if it loads large amounts of data."

Comment: Thanks @BoghyonHoffmann for your reply. unfortunately it does not work with smaller data too.

Comment: if I Remove Device.system.phone and then try I get this error :
https://photos.app.goo.gl/zNi5BR94H8H7o391A

Comment: Can't you simply reimplement the GET_STREAM method instead of this base64 hack?

Comment: No I am afraid thats not possible. @Marc

Comment: If blob URLs are blocked on mobile then I guess this is your only realistic alternative. Also using GET_STREAM is considered SAP standard and will make your frontend and backend code easier to read.

Comment: @Marc please share code snippet if you have any